# Gradle tasks do not run in parallel when they are supposed to

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, parallel-processing

I have a gradle task that depends on 4 other tasks. First of these is an "*assemble*" task that is basically supposed to build all the sub-projects of my project (I have a multi-project structure). It works fine.

The later three are all simple copying tasks. I want these three tasks to run in parallel to each other after the "*assemble*" task is fully complete, so I added "**mustRunAfter**" for every single one. However, tasks seem to only run one after another and not in parallel.

```
task parallelTask(dependsOn: ['assemble', 'copyOne', 
'copyTwo', 'copyThree']) {
    copyOne.mustRunAfter(assemble)
    copyTwo.mustRunAfter(assemble)
    copyThree.mustRunAfter(assemble)
}
```

Also, I have added **org.gradle.parallel=true** in my *gradle.properties*

I thought maybe the problem is with "**mustRunAfter**" annotation, so I created a separate task, that depends on all of the copying tasks like this:

```
task copyAll(dependsOn: ['copyOne', 
'copyTwo', 'copyThree']) {
}
task parallelTask(dependsOn: ['assemble', 'copyAll']) {
    copyAll.mustRunAfter(assemble)
}
```

However, now instead of waiting for "*assemble*" to finish, copying tasks seem to start simultaneously with "*assemble*", which I cannot have.

I need for my copying tasks to run in parallel after "*assemble*" is fully done for all of sub-projects of my project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`mustRunAfter` does not make any promisses of parallel execution, this is expected behavior. All this here says:

```
copyOne.mustRunAfter(assemble)
copyTwo.mustRunAfter(assemble)
copyThree.mustRunAfter(assemble)
```

is that `assemble` will run before the other three tasks and the three tasks will execute in some undefined order, *e.g.*  `copyThree` may run before `copyOne` or any other order.

If you want tasks to be explicitely ran in parallel, then you neet to tell Gradle that, Gradle will not do that by itself.

Look into this:

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/using-parallelizabletask/14634

You will need to declare task types: `type: ParallelTask`. However I do not have much experience with this particular type.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer! However, it seems like @ParallelizableTask has been removed since gradle 4. Now, it says that I can achieve the result using workerApi, so I'll look into it.